# Does a Vietnamese citzen need a Hong Kong visa to transfer to a ferry to Macau?

Tags: transit-visas, hong-kong, vietnamese-citizens, macau

I will take a trip from Vietnam to Hong Kong and then take a ferry to Macau. My flight will stop at terminal 2 (Vietjet Air). Do I need a Hong Kong visa? I do not want to go out into Hong Kong.

Can I go from Terminal 2 to SkyPier, and from SkyPier to Terminal 2? I hold a Vietnamese passport.

Answer (score 4):

No. You will not arrive at T2. Nobody does. T2 is not a real terminal: it is only for check-in. After land-side check-in, all departing passengers are rerouted to T1. Likewise, all arriving flights are fed into T1, whatever the airline. Once you get off the plane, you can walk to the SkyPier counter, and hand over your luggage tag: staff will go pick it up for you, and put it on your ferry. You can claim your luggage in Macao.

Likewise, when you leave Macao, you will check in at the ferry pier, and the ferry will take you to the international area, and after passing through security checks, you will be sent up to T1. VietJet Air is [one of the airlines](https://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/airport-ferry-services/macau-airport/macau-express-link-service.aspx) that participates to this "Macau express link service" program.

Comment: The list of airlines is actually here https://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/airport-ferry-services/hong-kong-airport/airlines-information.aspx . The passenger and baggage flow information here https://www.turbojet.com.hk/en/airport-ferry-services/hong-kong-airport/passenger-baggage-flow.aspx confirms, as this answer implies, that you do not pass through HK immigration en route to Macau. It is worth reading. I attempted to edit this info into the answer but the edit was rejected.